# How can I disable a wireless card (in order to upgrade to Windows 8.1?)

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-8.1, wireless-card

Hoping someone can help me with this, as I've been pulling my hair out over this issue since last October.

I'm unable to upgrade to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8. I've been trying since the update came out, with no luck.

I've updated all drivers, installed all updates for Windows and it still won't work. I think (and it may be a long shot) that the issue may be my Wireless card (Ralink 802.11n Wireless LAN Card, PCI) which I believe isn't supported by Windows 8.1

However, I can't think for the life of me how I'm going to be able to disable it. I've tried disabling it and un-installing it using Device Manager but it just keeps coming back.

Anyone have any ideas how I can get around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a laptop or PC? I see "PCI" for your wifi so assume PC. Could you just pull the card from the motherboard until your 8.1 update succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation, but i think you would be able to install the update if you just use an Ethernet cable. I had this issue, as my wireless card is dodgy, and i upgraded to windows 8.1 just by using an Ethernet cable (you can buy these from almost all computer shops. your wireless router should have an output for Ethernet on the back)

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm currently connected using an Ethernet cable and it's still not working. Thanks for the idea, though!